# Android error inflating class fragment, so how I can use maps with selectedFragment?

Tags: android-fragments

This is my code fragment. I just want to display maps in an activity when I selected on the tap fragment Near Me.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
Map m = new Map();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fm
            .beginTransaction();
    Fragment startFragment = new ViewAll();

    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_placeholder, startFragment);
    transaction.commit();

}

public void onSelectFragment(View view) {

    Fragment newFragment;

    if (view == findViewById(R.id.btnNearMe)) {
        newFragment = new NearMe();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.btnCategory)) {
        newFragment = new Category();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.btnViewAll)) {
        newFragment = new ViewAll();
    } else if (view == findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn)) {
        newFragment = new SignUpIn();
    } else {
        newFragment = new ViewAll();
    }

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();

}
```

Comment: shows us your code fragment code

Comment: post the stacktrace why did you delete it and post the line that causes the exception